# Does $f(x)=x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x^{2}})$ satisfy the relation $f(x)+f(y)-2f(\frac{x+y}{2})=O(|x-y|^{2})$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does $f(x)=x^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{x^{2}})$ satisfy the relation $f(x)+f(y)-2f(\frac{x+y}{2})=O(|x-y|^{2})$?

I can't check it. Who will hint it? Please.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\displaystyle\sin(x)\approx x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ so $$f(x)\approx x^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{6x^6}\right)=1-\frac{1}{6x^4}$$

(this is assuming $x$ is meant to be large)

Comment: vadim123. What about if $x\in (0, 1)$ ?

Comment: Then $|\sin \frac{1}{x^2}|\le 1$ so $|f(x)|\le x^2$.

Comment: vadim123. using this $|f(x)|\le x^{2}$ inequality how can I show that $f(x)$ satisfy relation $f(x)+f(y)-2f(\frac{x+y}{2})=O(|x-y|^{2})$